# Pipe filenames onto Rubocop

Tags: shell, ruby

I'm trying to pipe filnames into Rubocop as such:

```
$ git diff --name-only | tr '\n' ' ' | rubocop
```

However Rubocop still checks all project files.

Is there something wrong on my piping? On Rubocop? Somewhere else?

Comment: Did you try with  `rubocop --stdin`

Comment: `missing argument: --stdin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering myself because I discovered how to do it using [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).

`$ git diff --name-only | xargs rubocop`